# Only format IntelliJ on manually save, with autosave enabled

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, format, jetbrains-ide, autosave

I am coming from VSCode, where it autosaves files, but do not format them until you manually save it.
In IntelliJ I have set autosave for 1 second (the minimum), and I had reformat code on save enabled.

The problem is that by doing so it keeps formatting the code as I am writing it.

How can I set so that it always saves what I am coding, but only formats the code when I explicit saves the file?

I am using the IntelliJ Community Edition (version 2023.3.1)

Comment: As the files are already saved every second, maybe you can change the keyboard shortcut from Save All to Reformat Code? This way, when you try to manually save the file, reformat code will be invoked instead, but the file will be saved anyway after 1 second. Another option would be to create a macro with two actions: Reformat Code, Save All. Then assign a keyboard shortcut to this macro in the IDE Keymap settings. Then disable the reformat on save option. Will this work for you?